# Spring DI: Injection of FileInputStream in Constructor using annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I would like to inject a `FileInputStream` as a constructor argument using spring annotation.
Lets say I have the following class (before doing constructor arg injection)

```
@Component
public class MyClass{

    private BlaClass xy;


    public MyClass(InputStream is)
    {
     this.xy = new BlaClass(is);
    }

}
```

So now my question is if I can use the `@Value` annotation or a similar one in order to inject the input stream? Should be something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClass{

    private BlaClassTakingAnInputStream xy;

    //this is of course not correct
    public MyClass(@Value("classpath:path/to/a/file") is)
    {
     this.xy = new BlaClassTakingAnInputStream(is);
    }

}
```

p.s.: I know how it works using xml configuration but I would like to do it using annotations since its less verbose.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a `FileInputStream` for a resource on the classpath. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are right Sotirios. Actually I would like to get the resource and then do "resource.getInputStream()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Resource` like so

```
@Autowired
public MyClass(@Value("classpath:path/to/a/file") Resource resource) {
    // access to resource input stream
}
```

Note that the `@Autowired` is required to mark this constructor as the one to use. Otherwise, Spring would look for a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thx. This is what I was looking for. Sorry for the question that I asked in a wrong way ;-)